# magento 2 how can i get invoice of order placed with rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

In Magento 2 how can i get invoice of order placed with rest api,[image]
i tried like as shown in image. 49 was order Id.
but i am getting 
"Invoice Document Validation Error(s):\nYou can't create an invoice without products."
How can i get invoice for orders placed.

Answer (score 0):

The **order_item_id** is not the **order id**, it is the **Item Id** (it is coming from the products of the order)

[image]